# zend decorator easy way wrap dt label and dd input inside a div with the id of the input

Tags: html, zend-framework, hide, decorator

My goal is to let ZendForm generate my form in this way:
a DIV wrapper that include the normal DD and DT Zend tag...  My DIV need to have the ID tag with the id of the element like this:

```
<dl>
<div id="65-div">
<dt id="65-label"><label for="65" class="required">Nome</label></dt>
<dd id="65-element">
    <input type="text" name="65" id="65" value="">
</dd>
</div>
<div id="66-div">
...... ...
</div>
</dl>
```

I was able to reach my goal doing that:

```
$Element = $this->createElement('text', $result->request_field__ID);

$Element->clearDecorators()
->addDecorator('ViewHelper')
->addDecorator('Errors')
->addDecorator(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'dd', 'id'  => $Element->getId() . '-div', 'class' => 'zendData'))
->addDecorator(array('labelDivOpen' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'dt', 'placement' => 'prepend', 'closeOnly' => true))
->addDecorator('Label')
->addDecorator(array('labelDivClose' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'dt', 'id'  => $Element->getId() . '-label', 'class'=>'zendLabel','placement' => 'prepend', 'openOnly' => true))
->addDecorator(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div', 'id'  => $Element->getId() . '-div'));
```

**Is this the best way?**

Why I'm doing that?

Because I generate my form dinamically...  And I want to hide some fields and then display it with Jquery if some conditions happend...

In order to hide my field I use:

```
$Element->getDecorator('row')->setOptions(array('style' => 'display:none;'));
```

Is this also the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't look like valid HTML to me. You'd be much better off dropping the divs and using the IDs on the `dt` and `dd`  that are already there, so just display none those when you want to hide an element. Also, IDs cannot start with a number, so you might want to reverse your naming scheme so that it's `element-65` instead.